# Convert Date String to Day of Week

Tags: python, datetime

I have date strings like this:

```
'January 11, 2010'
```

and I need a function that returns the day of the week, like

```
'mon', or 'monday'
```

etc.
I can't find this anywhere in the Python help.
Anyone? Thanks.

Comment: use datetime module. http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior for more info.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

You might want to use [`strptime and strftime`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) methods from [`datetime`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html):

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('January 11, 2010', '%B %d, %Y').strftime('%A')
'Monday'
```

or for `'Mon'`:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('January 11, 2010', '%B %d, %Y').strftime('%a')
'Mon'
```

Answer (score 23):

use `date.weekday()`
Return the day of the week as an integer, where Monday is 0 and Sunday is 6.

http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.weekday

Answer (score 7):

A third-party parser could be used, such as [dateutil](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-dateutil).

And code for your original question:

```
>>> from dateutil import parser
>>> parser.parse('January 11, 2010').strftime("%a")
'Mon'
>>> parser.parse('January 11, 2010').strftime("%A")
'Monday'
```

Answer (score 6):

I think the fastest way to do it like below:

```
df[Date_Column].dt.weekday_name
```

Comment: Note that the syntax `dt.weekday_name` is for Pandas <= 0.22. For newer pandas versions you should use `dt.day_name()`.

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> import time
>>> dateStr = 'January 11, 2010'
>>> timestamp = time.strptime(dateStr, '%B %d, %Y')
>>> timestamp
time.struct_time(tm_year=2010, tm_mon=1, tm_mday=11, tm_hour=0, tm_min=0, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=0, tm_yday=11, tm_isdst=-1)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import time

time.strftime('%A')
```