# how to get day of week from datetime in CSV (Y.M.D,)

Tags: python, csv, google-sheets

I am trying to figure out how to turn date time from a csv into the day of week equivelant,
i have a column in a CSV with date format as listed below (Y.M.D) and i want to turn that into mon, tue, wed, thur, fri, sat, sun, instead.
 I have data corresponding to each date, 
 I need a variable for each day of the 7 day week for an ML model. (Im trying to see if theres a correlation between my dependant variables and the specific day of the week)

I want to turn this

```
Day
2019.12.24
2019.12.26
2019.12.27
2019.12.28
2019.12.29
2019.12.30
2019.12.31
```

into this

```
Day
'Wednesday'
'Thursday'
'Friday'
'Saturday'
'Sunday'
'Monday'
'Tuesday'
```

The data is In a CSV in google sheets if anyone knows how to do it in there (google sheets) that would be ideal, or in Python that would be good as well, any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert Date String to Day of Week](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16766643/convert-date-string-to-day-of-week)

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert your string into datetime obj like that:
And then you will be able to export day [or any other date property]

```py
def date_to_week_day(date_time_str):
  date_time_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_time_str, '%Y-%m-%d')
  logging.debug( date_time_obj.isoweekday())
  return date_time_obj.isoweekday()
```

Answer (score 1):

In google-sheets

Begin with [search_replace](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/62754?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) `.` with `-` for your date column
then run

`=CHOOSE( weekday(A1), "Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat")`

Answer (score 0):

If you'd prefer to do this in Google Sheets and not modify the Day column, you can use the following formula to get the day of the week:

```
=TEXT(DATE(INDEX(SPLIT(A2, "."), 0, 1), INDEX(SPLIT(A2, "."), 0, 2), INDEX(SPLIT(A2, "."), 0, 3)), "dddd")
```